# Why would i use my own defined scopes rather than @Singleton in Dagger 2?

Tags: android, dagger-2

In Dagger 2 you can create scopes. Why would i do this over using the @Singleton annotation?

For example this code is from a fork of u2020 (originally created by Jake Wharton). It defines an Application scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApplicationScope {
}
```

Here we have another scope that defines a Gallery scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GalleryScope {
}
```

All source code can be found here: [u2020 using Dagger 2](https://github.com/LiveTyping/u2020-mvp)

Is the difference literally semantics and they both do the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this issue on Github | Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107).

Comment: Thanks, but i'm struggling to understand how that helps me with my question. Can you explain?

Comment: In your question, neither `@ApiEndpoint` nor `@IsMockMode` are scopes.  They are qualifiers as they are annotated with `javax.inject.Qualifier`.  Scope annotations are annotated with `javax.inject.Scope`.  I think it would help to clarify whether your question is about qualifiers or scopes.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't see that...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, i've been trying to learn how to use Dagger 2 for the past week and i may have gone slightly crazy.

Comment: crazy it is!!! I know what you went through... But once understood it's best part... Clean code... My dream come true... haha